# Trying to make PK font tfrupee at 657 DPI

Tags: fonts, errors, miktex

I am getting an error of The `tfrupee source file could not be found`, which is a part of [tfrupee](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tfrupee) package. I was trying to insert the rupee symbol. I am using MikTeX 2.9 + TeXmaker + Windows 7.

I am not very tech friendly person and I am learning LaTeX.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: `\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tfrupee}
\begin{document}
\rupee
\end{document}`

Comment: May be Update MiKTeX `Use the Start menu to start MiKTeX Options.Click Refresh FNDB` and above code should work. I don't have MiKTeX to test.

Comment: The miktex package seems to be faulty, it doesn't activate the map file correctly. Add `\pdfmapfile{=tfrupee.map}` to your document and make a bug report.

Comment: Thanks to all of you. The solution by Ulrike Fischer worked. I am grateful to him and all of you for your suggestion. I am feeling great to be in this forum.

Answer (score 4):

### Update:

Text below is now historic. The bug was fixed in February 2014, cf. linked bug entry.

---

It seems to be a problem of the MiKTeX package `tfrupee` itself: The map file though present in the package is not activated, i.e. the contents are not copied into the distribution wide configuration file.

As a workaround you can add the following line into your document

```
\pdfmapfile{=tfrupee.map}
```

But a real solution can only be done by the developer of MiKTeX. For this, a bug is filed in the [MiKTeX Bug tracker](https://sourceforge.net/p/miktex/) under [font tfrupe not activated](https://sourceforge.net/p/miktex/bugs/2302/) (yes, with typo).

Comment: This bug is started again with MikTeX since yesterday. I didn't face this issue earlier with previous installer. I just uninstalled earlier version due to space crunch on my system few days. When I downloaded and installed the MikTeX x64 again yesterday, I faced this issue with pdfLaTeX though it works the above mentioned workaround. However, I don't have any issue with XeLaTeX. Just wondering how to resolve this in pdfLaTeX too!